# Convert Keystore - Windows-my to jks

Tags: java, pkcs#12, jks

We are using SunMSCAPI to retrieve the current user keystore as below..

```
keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
```

We will need to build a JSSE keystore of type JKS/PKCS12 and pass it to an app..

Sort of beginning to understand how this works.. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
keystore.load(inputStreamFromOriginalFile, password);
KeyStore keystore2 = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
for (String name : toIterable(keystore.aliases())) {
    Entry entry = keystore.getEntry(name, protParam);
    keystore2.setEntry(name, entry, protParam);
}
keystore2,store(outputStream, password);
```

I mean a dump copy of all entries into a new keystore2.

Comment: Thanks. getentry/setentry doesnt work. It tries to find the keyformat and keyencoding and both are set to null. Throws the below exception. Looks like we cant really do this. java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:409)

Comment: I'd suppose, it is possible, but needs to set the key protection algorithm, whatever it is. The whole API is much more cryptic than cryptographic. Btw., do you know http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ It may be able to do it, or you can at least inspect the source code.

Comment: Thank you for the kind help. I reviewed the source or portecle. It does the same.. Gets the key, certchain and setskeyentry.. I am able to do the same to convert a JKS store to a PKCS12, but not for this specific purpose. When we retrieve the key from this store using SunMSCAPI, the format and the encoding of the key is not specified causing null pointers..

Comment: That's strange. You get an exception when trying to *set* an Entry for a JSK or PKCS12 keystore, and you can otherwise work with such keystores. Did you tried to pass a `new PasswordProtection(password)` as a parameter? Did you tried to export everything from the keystore (e.g., to files) and load it to the new one? Using either a program or portacle?

Comment: Sorry. I do not get any exception when i try to convert from JKS to PKCS12. I only get the exception when converting from Windows-my to anything else..

Comment: I did pass new PasswordProtection(password) to setEntry and still get the same exception.